# Shutdown animation sound

Tags: shutdown, custom-sounds

I have an issue, when I shutdown the phone, it gives a custom sound. I want to remove it. The phone is LG G3 (Rooted).

I tried to delete the sound using root explorer.

Answer (score 1):

To mute them, Simply do the Following :

In System > Sound and Display > System volume you can set it, unfortunately the power on/off sound is also tied to the touch feedback sound.

You can also use [Silent Boot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antweb.silentboot&hl=en).

[image: Silent Boot apk]

> Note:Disable annoying startup sounds! Silent Boot mutes your phone on
>   shutdown to keep it silent on boot and restores previous volume
>   settings after startup is complete. Please note: This workaround does
>   not apply to all phones

***Lastly, Here the one which I followed :***

1) First off all download the Root browser from play store.

2) Open it, the app will ask you to install some additional data, don’t cancel it – otherwise the app may not work properly.

3) Now when the additional download complete, search for the System folder & open it, followed by Media or sound folder.

[image: Android Boot Sound]

4) Here you will get two  files namely PowerOn.mp3 & PowerOff.mp3

5) So long press the PowerON.mp3 file > choose Rename > rename the file to PowerON.mp3.bak. Same with the PowerOff.mp3 file, rename it to PowerOff.mp3.bak.

That’s it, now reboot your phone and there should be no shut down and start up sound.

So if you’re happy with permanently turning off the sound, then your steps end here. You can leave this guide now. But if you want to replace the default android boot sound with any mild music then follow this steps.

6) Now download the soft sound which you would like to set as boot sound.

7) Copy that to System / Media folder & rename it to PowerON.mp3 & power Off.mp3

8) Now long press on new sound file, select permission from popup.

9) Tick all the boxes that appears after selecting permission, then press OK

10) Now every time your reboot your phone you will be welcomed with your new boot sound.

***Note :- Make sure to keep the new boot sound file length with in 10 sec. Otherwise you will feel double irritating.***

Comment: @user124844: Don't forget to Click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means this answer is valid, as regarding to http://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer and http://android.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote